# How to upgrade EasyPhp to php 5.4?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, easyphp

The easyphp is currently at 5.3.9, I need the newest. I downloaded the latest php package from php.net, and deleted the old php and copied the new php directory. I try "`phpinfo();`", first it displays the result, but at the end Windows 7 says apache has crashed. How to upgrate to the newest php? Errors.log:

```
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3900
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Child 3900: Child process is running
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Child 3900: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Child 3900: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed May 16 09:38:36 2012] [notice] Child 3900: Starting thread to listen on port 8887.
[Wed May 16 09:39:03 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2764
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Child process is running
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed May 16 09:39:04 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Starting thread to listen on port 8887.
[Wed May 16 09:39:23 2012] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed May 16 09:39:23 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed May 16 09:39:24 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Released the start mutex
[Wed May 16 09:39:25 2012] [notice] Child 2764: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed May 16 09:39:25 2012] [notice] Child 2764: Child process is exiting
[Wed May 16 09:39:25 2012] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5712
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Child 5712: Child process is running
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Child 5712: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Child 5712: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed May 16 09:40:46 2012] [notice] Child 5712: Starting thread to listen on port 8887.
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3972
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Child process is running
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed May 16 09:41:01 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Starting thread to listen on port 8887.
[Wed May 16 09:42:20 2012] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed May 16 09:42:20 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed May 16 09:42:21 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Released the start mutex
[Wed May 16 09:42:22 2012] [notice] Child 3972: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed May 16 09:42:22 2012] [notice] Child 3972: Child process is exiting
[Wed May 16 09:42:22 2012] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not the exact answer you're looking for.. I used to use EasyPHP until I realized that their updates come very, very slowly. Since then I've started using [The Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) instead, which offers more or less the same tools, but more frequent updates and can be also run from USB.